Looking across a row to display the column heading
My department covers several different wards of a hospital
Our current rota is arranged so that the first column is the date, the heading of subsequent columns are consultant names - the cells are filled with ward names e.g. Ward A, Ward B, Ward C - a bit like this:



Date
Dr X
Dr Y
Dr z




Mon
Ward A
Ward B
Ward C


Tues
Ward A
Clinic
Ward C



Each month I need to prepare a summary for the deparment which is displayed by Ward 0 -i.e. on such a day, Dr Y is covering ward A - so essentially I need a formula that can look across a specific day, if it finds a match for Ward A, will then display the column heading for that match. Any idea on how to do that?
Another curveball is that there may be potentially two Drs covering the same area... so can it display 2 names? Or does that get too complicated.
I'm very new to this and tried look up and indexing, but am new to all of this and couldn't get it to work! Edited to add I'm working from excel 2010

Do you have your data formatted as a table (with table and column names)? Or just as raw data? How are your dates formatted? Just mon, tue, ... or with an actual date? (mon 10/14, tue 10/15)? Also, which version of Excel do you have?

Hi - Excel version 2010 (this is the NHS for you!). The dates are formatted UK DD/DD/YY, the rest is just raw data

Ah well, then I need to edit my answer, because as it stands, it'll only work for Excel 2021 and higher. Can you please [edit] this info into your original question?

@SandwellWestBirminghamHopsi found this Microsoft Office 365 for the NHS - NHS England Digital

Edit, for older Excel:
This, however, only gives you the first found output:
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1;;MATCH(I3;INDEX($B$2:$D$4;MATCH(H3;$A$2:$A$4);)))

With B1:D1 being your headers (blue), B2:D4 are your wards (purple), and A2:A4 are your dates (red).
Input is H2 is your date you're looking for, and I2 is the ward you're looking for.
I think there might be a CSE method available with INDEX/SMALL or INDEX/AGGREGATE that can give multiple outputs, but I haven't worked enough with those.


Previous method, applicable for excel 2021+
Here's one method:
=FILTER($B$1:$D$1,CHOOSEROWS($B$2:$D$4,XMATCH(H3,$A$2:$A$4))=I3)

With B1:D1 being your headers (blue), B2:D4 are your wards (red), and A2:A4 are your dates (green).
Input is H2 is your date you're looking for, and I2 is the ward you're looking for.
This will be able to output multiple doctors on one place for one date.


This is great - With this method, can you modify to search for a cell containing partial ward information. For example if the cell contained Ward A/Ward B? Could it pull that individual's name to both areas?

Use the following formula as array entry for Excel-2010.
=INDEX(A1:D1,SUMPRODUCT((B2:D3=G4)*(A2:A3=F4)*(COLUMN(B2:D3))))

or using MMULT().
=INDEX(B1:D1,MATCH(1,MMULT({1,1},--(B2:D3=G4)*(A2:A3=F4)),0))

Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.


There is no alternative to MMULT() very nice

Not been able to test this on an actual copy of Excel 2010, but theoretically you should be able to expand this with AGGREGATE and IFERROR, like this: =IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$D$1,AGGREGATE(14,3,MMULT({1,1},--($A$2:$A$3=$G3)*--($B$2:$D$3=$H3)*(COLUMN($B$1:$D$1)-1)),{1,2,3,4}*--({1,2,3,4}<=SUM(--($A$2:$A$3=$G3)*--($B$2:$D$3=$H3))))),"") This should output names of up to 4 doctors per Day/Ward combo.  (To output up to, say, 6 doctors, change both {1, 2, 3, 4}s to {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})

This is based on a monthly report, so there's going to up to 31 rows, OP would need to {1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1} in the MMULT version? Also, the SUMPRODUCT one seems to fail on me if there's two doctors on the same ward on the same day. Could be me though.

@Excellor An easier way than that would be to make it dynamic to the reference: --TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$2:A$32)>0)  Then you can even use Named Ranges for rngDays, rngDoctors and rngWards (since Excel2010 does not support LET): =INDEX(rngDoctors,MATCH(1,MMULT(--TRANSPOSE(ROW(rngDays)>0),--(rngWards=G4)*(rngDays=F4)),0))


For ease of use when adding new rows and also for writing and maintaining formulae, I would recommend inserting tables for your data.

For partial match, enter the wildcard * in ward's name - for example

*C means match words ending in c, so it will match both Clinic and Ward C
*abc* means match that contains abc


In this example I've named them Roster and Report



With the tables defined, in the first cell of column Doctor(s) in Report enter the following:
=CONCAT(IF(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("~*", [@Ward])),
ISNUMBER(SEARCH([@Ward], INDEX(Roster, MATCH([@Date], Roster[Date], 0), ))),
INDEX(Roster, MATCH([@Date], Roster[Date], 0), ) = [@Ward]),
Roster[#Headers] & ", ", ""))

If you get an error, please try entering by pressing Control + Shift + Enter
Formatted code:
=CONCAT(
    IF(
        IF(
            ISNUMBER(SEARCH("~*", [@Ward])),
            ISNUMBER(
                SEARCH([@Ward], INDEX(Roster, MATCH([@Date], Roster[Date], 0), ))
            ),
            INDEX(Roster, MATCH([@Date], Roster[Date], 0), ) = [@Ward]
        ),
        Roster[#Headers] & ", ",
        ""
    )
)




Step





Match with wildcard or not
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("~*", [@Ward]))


Look up row by date
INDEX(Roster, MATCH([@Date], Roster[Date], 0), )


For partial match, use SEARCH
ISNUMBER(SEARCH([@Ward],


For exact match, use =
 = [@Ward]


Match doctor's name in header
(Roster[#Headers]


Append delimiter
& ", "


Join the results
CONCAT(...)




Just to keep the code short, I'm not removing the extraneous "," and the end. Please let me know if you want it removed.

I hope CONCAT works under Excel 2010.


CONCAT (which supports Arrays as Input) was added in Excel 2016.  Excel 2010 only has CONCATENATE, which requires individual Scalar arguments as Input.

@Chronocidal, thank you! That's too bad. Do you know how to join text arrays in 2010? The oldest version I have is 2016.

You use a VBA UDF, or… you don't.  Well, unless you can output the Array to a known range, and then do =CONCAT(A1 &", ", A2 & ", ", A3 & ", "…), sum up the lengths of all the values in the array, add 2*(items_in_array - 1), and take the LEFT that_many_characters
